# php file as xml for flash

Tags: php, html, xml, flash

guys i got a php file that use it as xml for a flash object the problem is when is put $_get in the php file i get the same output but the flash doesnt work but if i remove the $_get variable it worksss

Comment: Are you not forgetting to close the <menu> element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put in the closing '</menu>', without it your xml will be invalid

Btw, it's more readable and easy to create xml from ordinary array/object with SimpleXML class, or like that.

Comment: i ve added the cloding tag but the problem is still there

Comment: Please, check if both your files (php-generated xml and ordinary xml, which is working), having same data, are identical (you can use 'cmp' if you're using linux, or some free file diff tool for windows). Maybe there are some extra spaces (or anything, that cant be seen) in your php-code, which causes the mess for flash

Comment: thanks alot man the problem is fixed after the changing xmlPath=photostack.xml to xmlPath=photoStack.xml,, very weird problem though

Comment: If the machine serving up the flash file and XML file have a case sensitive file system (anything but windows) then this makes perfect sense.  The only way this would work is if the machine hosting the site was Windows based... and that wouldn't make sense :)

Comment: i got aother problem now though when i echo a line inside a loop the first iteration is only considerd in the xml ????!?!?!